# Exporting/Importing all function info from one ghidra program to another

Tags: decompilation, ghidra

I'm looking for a way to export all infos about a function (Call signature including custom storage, local symbols, etc) in a ghidra program and import them into another ghidra program, but at a different address, and to do that automatically for 30-50 functions.

This is within the context of a very large game executable, enough so that any form of full analysis is way too cumbersome for my needs, and each game patch shuffles most of the addresses. I already have most of that automated, but through manually defining serialiazation code for function elements like parameters, and was wondering if there was any better way.

Comment: I am dealing with a similar situation. did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @ghidrauto I never found a built-in solution no, so I wrote scripts to handle it myself, you can find tthem there : https://github.com/Strackeror/GhidraScripts